# Add title to vimeo video through nodejs vimeo api?

Tags: node.js, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am writing an application to upload a video file to vimeo .
The problem is the title is always set to "Untitled"!
Is there any way to set the title of the video while uploading through the api?
I am using [This api](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.js/releases)

Have a look

Comment: looking through the api, i dont see any way to do that during the upload, maybe a request to change the name after the upload, have you tried that?

Comment: ya i am trying a patch request to do that which vimeo provides!
I am unable to pass the new title properly.
[look at this](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/videos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docs for PATCH-ing your video post-upload are [here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/videos#PATCH/videos/%7Bvideo_id%7D).

Name and title are one and the same. The docs look a little confusing right now so I'll clean those up.

In node, the code looks like this

```
var response = lib->request({method:'PATCH', path:video_uri, query:{name:'New Name'}});
```